# use grep and cut command to get output of each line in next line

Tags: bash

```
$ cat hello.txt     
shreenivasa hi hello this is test mail                      
shreenivasa how are you man
```

if i run in terminal

```
$ cat hello.txt | grep shreenivasa | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

its giving following output

```
hi hello this is test mail      
how are you man
```

but if i write it as script in `hello.sh` like below

```
#!/bin/bash
hi=`cat hello.txt | grep shreenivasa | cut -d ' ' -f 2-`
echo $hi
```

output for `./hello.sh` is

```
hi hello this is test mail how are you man.
```

I want to print "how are you man" in next line
like

```
hi hello this is test mail     
how are you man
```

tried `$hi\n` didn't work

Comment: please review [how do I format my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and then (re)format the question

Comment: As a start, since you are using `grep` you do not need to use `cat`.  Grep reads files. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: try wrapping the variable reference in double quotes: `echo "$hi"`; see [difference between single and double quotes in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753) for more details

Comment: Please c.f. [this page](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award) on things like avoiding `cat` as an extra process when `grep` would have opened the file and been more efficient without it. Generally an antipattern.  It's a small bit if data, so not a system-killing error, but try not to get in the habit.  Try just `grep -oP '(?<=shreenivasa ).*' hello.txt` or `sed -nE '/^shreenivasa /{s/^shreenivasa //; p;}' hello.txt`, and as a habit, always double-quote your variables when you use them unless there's a reason *not* to do so....